# Get request and query string

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm trying to get some information from my route by an ajax call. I have to query strings I need to fetch in the route.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/servers',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {ip: serverIp, port: serverPort},
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success" + data);
})
```

However, console returns 404. I'm not sure how to exactly get this request in my routes.

```
Route::get('/servers', function(){
         $ip = Input::get('ip');
         $port = Input::get('port');
         return $ip . $port; // checking if it works
});
```

Eventually this will be a request to router to controller, but I'm just trying to get the ajax request to work first. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have no experience in laravel, but looks like the examples omit the `/` in the beginning. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this to retrieve `POST/GET` inputs:

```
$ip = Input::get('ip');
$port = Input::get('port');
```

But in this case (for a query strung) your `URI` should contain them, for example:

```
http://example.com/servers?ip=serverIp&port=serverPort
```

So, pass them with your `URL` in `ajax`

```
// query string: ?ip=serverIp&port=serverPort
url: '/servers?ip='+serverIp+'&port='+serverPort
```

If you use `POST` request and probably you should then, in this case you may try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/servers',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {ip: serverIp, port: serverPort}
})
.done(...)
```

The server side code to retrieve the data from `POST` remains same only change the route declaration to `post`. Check more ([Retrieving An Input Value](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#basic-input)) on `Laravel` website.

Comment: Hi thanks, sadly it's still returning 404. GET http://localhost/servers?ip=ip.com&port=25555 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Which one you used ? `POST` or `GET`? What is your `route` and declaration?

Comment: Use `Route::post(...)` instead of `Route::get(...)` and use the same `JS` code but change `type: 'GET'` to `type: 'POST'`.